# Как думаете, чем так закодировали?

Tags: lua

```
local function f(c) return string.char(tonumber(c, 16)) end; local function from(m) return string.gsub(m, "(..)", f) end; loadstring(from("1b4c756150010404040608090908b6099368e7f57d41080000003d286e6f6e652900000000000000007a0000000000000000000000000a0000000407000000737472696e6700040500000063686172000407000000666f726d6174000405000000677375620004040000007375620004050000006d6174680004040000006d6f640003000000000000f03f0300000000000000400300000000000008402400000000000000080000002000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000002200000003800f0008800f1f08000f1e08800e1d08000e1c08800d1b08000d1a08800c1908000c1808800b1708000b1608800a1508000a14088009130800091208800811080008100880070f0800070e0880060d0800060c0880050b0800050a088004090800040808800307080003060880020508000204088001030800010208800001080000001b800000000000000e0000001f00001f00000000000000000000000000000000000000002100000003000f0008000f1e08800e1d08000e1c08800d1b08000d1a08800c1908000c1808800b1708000b1608800a1508000a14088009130800091208800811080008100880070f0800070e088006..
```

Comment: Вы об этой длинной строке HEX значений для символов?

Comment: Именно, хотелось бы ее в читаемый вид. :(

Answer (score 4):

В вышеприведённом коде явно видно, как происходит декодирование.

1. Из входной строки последовательно берётся по два символа — `string.gsub(m, "(..)", f)`.
2. Полученные два символа, представляющие собой запись числа в шестнадцатиричной системе счисления, конвертируются в число в десятичной системе счисления — `tonumber(c, 16)`.
3. Полученное число есть ни что иное, как код символа. Вызов `string.char(…)` получает символ по его коду.
4. Совокупность символов, полученных на п. 3 и есть результат декодирования входной строки.

Зная последовательность действий для декодирования, алгоритм кодирования становится очевидным.

После декодирования исходной строки получаем некий бинарный контент, который, при детальном рассмотрении, оказывается скомпилированным байт-кодом Lua. Об этом свидетельствует сигнатура `*LuaR*` в заголовке бинарного контента. В общем-то, это вполне ожидаемо, поскольку `loadstring` принимает либо непосредственно Lua-скрипт, либо скомпилированный Lua-chunk.

Comment: Сколько искал в Интернете, так и не нашел зацепок для декодирования.

Comment: Для декодирования чего? Байт-кода Lua? Это странно, ведь по первому же запросу находится как его подробная спецификация ([раз][1], [два][2]), так и декомпиляторы, например, [LuaDec][3]. Как-то вы странно искали.

  [1]: http://wiki.luajit.org/Bytecode-2.0
  [2]: http://luaforge.net/docman/83/98/ANoFrillsIntroToLua51VMInstructions.pdf
  [3]: http://luadec.luaforge.net/